# How to fire keyup event on clipboard using jquery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, clipboard

I want to fire keyup event on a pdf doc which is open in chrome browser. Is it possible or not?One of my friend told me it can be happened with clipboard object.
I don't know he is right or wrong?
Please tell it can be happened or not?

Answer (score -1):

Is it an arbitrary pdf document from the web or did you create it yourself? You can add javascript to an pdf document when you create it yourself:

http://www.pdfill.com/document_javascript.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wipster.I am not creating this pdf doc I am just open this pdf just click on pdf url in Chroem browser.

Comment: Your welcome. In this case I don't think it's possible, because chrome opens its own pdf viewer to display a pdf doc. But you should have a look at this: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/
I have no idea how the clipboard could help with this situation though!

Comment: If you can share any link related to Google chrome then it's really helpful for me.Thanks

Comment: It's javascript and HTML5. It's supposed to work on every up-to-date browser. Just tested it on chromium 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu.